# An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

changed the sonar version from *3.7* to *sonarqube 5.1.1*. and ran the build from jenkins getting Error

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project integration-client: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/api/utils/SonarException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

i am using the **java version 1.6** and **maven version 3.2.3**

previously with sonar 3.7 version it was working fine.

Comment: you will need to use a JDK 1.7 to avoid this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error

Comment: i dont want to change the jdk so upto which sonar version jdk1.6 will work and have scm clearcase plugin.

Comment: the sonar docs http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements are not available for older versions. I would give the 4.5 LTS version a try. Notice these JDK are no longer supported.
It's one thing how you compile the project - it's another thing how the sonar-server or the sonar-plugin runs.

Comment: sonarqube 4.3.3 and scm activity plugin 1.8 is working in java 1.6. i am getting the blame information but not getting the coverage on new code in the dashboard

Comment: Here is the detailed answer I wrote for a similar question. Following the same steps might be helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989454/6565832