# An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have upgraded from 7.6>7.9>8.9>9.0.

And now we are facing the same issue,

plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I have gone through the documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/#header-3, but how can we user sonar.java.jdkHome and where? And this jdk should be on jenkins slave or sonarqube server?
We dont use the sonarqube properties file, we have jenkins build where we have maven config and only sonar:sonar for scans. How can we manage this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run on JDK8 instead of JDK11. SonarQube server has to run on JDK11 as far as I know...

Comment: yes its up and running on jdk11, but the project uses jdk 8 and while scanning it give above exception, now the issue is - https://community.sonarsource.com/t/an-api-incompatibility-was-encountered-encountered-error-upon-execute-of-mvn-sonar-sonar-on-project/46876/4

Comment: We had similar problem when SQ went from min JDK 6 -> 8. Changed our jobs to build using  job default JDK 6, then add [envinject ENV step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk8, then called sonar scanner step. See if that works for you, but 8 -> 11. Also, Jenkins mastee and agents ran 8,  SQ rruns 11. Your jobs can use anything configured in Global Tools Java.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Since SonarQube 9.0 analysis must be done using JDK11. This is one of the breaking changes in 9.0, see official [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-with-java-11/).

Comment: any workaround for scanning java8 applications?

Comment: You can build your project with JDK8 and only run the scanner with JDK11 or JDK17. See the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanner-environment/) for examples.

Comment: The documentation link above is broken - 9.0 probably reached EOL. Fresh link for the same thing: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/#supported-platforms Note the version combobox on the upper left of the documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and after a lot of attempts doing multiple things, I saw this line somewhere in the documentation:

> The requirements above refer only to the versions of Java and Node.js
> used by the scanner itself to run. It does not restrict the versions
> of Java, JavaScript, TypeScript or CSS that can be analyzed by the
> scanner.

So, I ran my projects normally using the existing java version and **right before running the sonar I changed the JAVA_HOME so that sonar scanner can run using the java version required by the scanner.**

Firstly I checked what all java versions are present on my system using the below command:

```
mdfind -name 'java' | grep '/bin/java$'
```

Got something like this in the result:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.6/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/20/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.18/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+362/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
```

in my case I had jdk17 installed on my system already.
In case it is missing, please install jdk11 or jdk17 because it is required by the scanner.

After that, using the path of jdk17 from the above results, I changed my JAVA_HOME to point to jdk11 location using the below command:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.6/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home'
```

once JAVA_HOME is changed, sonarqube can be run normally to give the desired result using the below command:

```
mvn sonar:sonar   -Dsonar.projectKey={{PROJECT_KEY}}  -Dsonar.projectName={{PROJECT_NAME}}   -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.token={{SONAR_TOKEN}}
```

**Reference Docs:**

Sonalqube Environment Setup: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanner-environment/

How to install and setup sonarqube on local: https://techblost.com/how-to-setup-sonarqube-locally-on-mac/